# Loop in basic C program

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, differential-equations

I can't find and resolve the error in this code.
I want Parray and Tarray to be filled with an iteration of the equation in the loop. I tried both for and while loop, but it seems that only the first member of the array is given proper value, and that value is lost by the beginning of a new cycle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int i;
    int j;
    float dt,P_init,t_init,t_end;
    dt = 0.03125;
    P_init = 30;
    t_init = 0;
    t_end = 30;

    int n_steps = 0;
    n_steps = t_end/(float)dt;

    int Parray[n_steps+1];
    int Tarray[n_steps+1];

    for (i=0; i<n_steps+1; i++)
       {
           Parray[i]=0;
           Tarray[i]=0;
       }



    Parray[0] = P_init;
    Tarray[0] = t_init;

    int x;
    float P,t,dpdt;

    x = 1;
    while (x < n_steps+1)
       {

        float s,d;
        P = Parray[x-1];
        t = Tarray[x-1];
        dpdt = 0.7 * P * (1-(P/750)) - 20;
        s = P + (dt * dpdt);
        Parray[x] = s;
        d = t + dt;
        Tarray[x] = d;
        x++;
        printf("%f  %f  ",s,d);

               }



    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i, j, x;
    float dt, P_init, t_init, t_end, P, t, dpdt;

    dt = 0.03125;
    P_init = 30;
    t_init = 0;
    t_end = 30;

    int n_steps = 0;
    n_steps = t_end / (float)dt;

    // using float arrays
    float Parray[n_steps+1];
    float Tarray[n_steps+1];

    for (i = 0; i < n_steps+1; i++)
           Parray[i] = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < n_steps+1; j++)
           Tarray[j] = 0;

    Parray[0] = P_init;
    Tarray[0] = t_init;

    for (x = 1; x < n_steps + 1; x++) {
        float s , d;
        P = Parray[x-1]; 
        t = Tarray[x-1];
        dpdt = 0.7 * P * (1 - (P / 750)) - 20;
        s = P + (dt * dpdt);
        Parray[x] = s;
        d = t + dt;
        Tarray[x] = d;
        printf("%f  %f\n", s, d);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I changed the int arrarys to float arrays.
What do you actually calculate here?

Comment: I compiled it, and output is again repeating itself. dpdt = 0.7 * P * (1 - (P / 750)) - 20;
s = P + (dt * dpdt); this two equations should calculate next iteration of Parray.

Comment: My output is in the last two itarations 720.240845  29.968750
720.240967  30.000000. I tried it with two compilers.

Comment: Inspect the for loop with a debugger if s and d is calculated correctly.

Comment: I checked your calculation in python, and it is right, so thanks. I guess there is something wrong with my C compiler.

Comment: Unlikely. Try this online compiler: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
dpdt = 0.7 * P * (1-(P/750)) - 20;
```

It seems to have a float value, therefore the array must be float type, and ALL inputs you put in the array must be in FLOAT type.
Change this:

```
int Parray[n_steps+1];
int Tarray[n_steps+1];
```

to

```
float Parray[n_steps+1];
float Tarray[n_steps+1];
```

and

```
P_init = 30;
t_init = 0;
t_end = 30;
```

All of them should be 30.0, 0.0, 30.0
Don't forget this too:

```
 Parray[i]=0;
 Tarray[i]=0;
```

Change it to 0.0

In short, C is bad at differentiate between types, so if you declare a float array, all inputs must be x.0, not only x where x is an integer.

Comment: OK. I don't think that's the problem here. But when you use float literals then use something like this 30f. 30.0 notation is for double values.

Comment: I got the correct result now, by changing the original code only by float Parray initialization, instead of  int. So P_init and t_init were not the problems.